# Checking a website for notification Android

Tags: android, notifications

I'm working on an Android project.

I have a website that sends picture and i wrote an app for receiving that picture. But i don't know how to wrote a code which when i added a photo to the site, in my app, a notification shows up.

Now, i check the last picture name which i save it in my app and the new picture name which is on the site and if they were different, i download the photo and save it. But this an one-time process and it happened when user click on refresh button.

How to do this automatically?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at `GCM` (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)? Maybe you can register the Android Device on your website server and push a notification every time that someone add a photo, so your device can be notified of this action.

Comment: i don't have a server here!! i just have a simple php and i want to check it sometimes for new pictures. like what facebook app does for its notifications!!